# Why making a new array using map

Tags: javascript

What is the use of making another array by using map ,so i need one reason to make a new array using map because i have watched many tutorials but didn't understand
What is the difference between using this

```
     ids = data.allItems[type].map(function(current){
         return current.id;
     }) 
     index = ids.indexOf(id)
     console.log(index)
     if(index !== -1){
         data.allItems[type].splice(index,1) //[0,1,2,3,4]
     }
```

and this

```
    ids = data.allItems[type][id]
   index = data.allItems[type].indexOf(ids)
        if(index !== -1){
        data.allItems[type].splice(index,1) //[0,1,2,3,4]
    }
```

both are doing the same function

Comment: It's a little difficult to explain it with no knowledge of the context. If you can provide more information (the object you're using for example) I could try to explain to you why and if `map` is the best choice in such scenario.

Comment: I read a little about it and i think it's use is to make some categories of the Array such as to make an array of the age or name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` allows transforming the elements of an array, this implies several advantages

For example given the following list of employees

```
const employees = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "john",
    lastName: "doe",
    salary: 10000,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    firstName: "andy",
    lastName: "johnson",
    salary: 15000,
  },
];
```

And suppose you require only their salaries, you can do the following

```
const salaries = employees.map((employee) => employee.salary);

// output [ 10000, 15000 ]
```

Now suppose you need to get their salaries next to their full names, you can try the following

```
const employeeList = employees.map(({ id, firstName, lastName, salary }) => ({
  id,
  fullName: `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
  salary,
}));

// output [{ fullName: 'john doe', salary: 10000 }, { fullName: 'andy johnson', salary: 15000 }]
```

You accomplish this without loops, which is a plus

Another advantage is that it allows you to avoid unexpected results, for example imagine that you need a copy of the list of employees

```
const newEmployees = employees;
```

And then you modify the salary of one of the employees from the original list

```
employees[0].salary = 25000;
```

This operation will affect both lists, as you can see here

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(employees, null, 2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(newEmployees, null, 2));

output

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "john",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "salary": 25000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "andy",
    "lastName": "johnson",
    "salary": 15000
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "john",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "salary": 25000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "andy",
    "lastName": "johnson",
    "salary": 15000
  }
]
```

John has salary of 25000 in the original list and the new list. The reason is that copies by reference

To avoid this, map allows you to copy to get a new list and in consequence free of unexpected results

```
const anotherNewEmployess = employees.map(
  ({ id, firstName, lastName, salary }) => ({ id, firstName, lastName, salary })
);

output

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "john",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "salary": 25000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "andy",
    "lastName": "johnson",
    "salary": 15000
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "john",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "salary": 10000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "andy",
    "lastName": "johnson",
    "salary": 15000
  }
]
```

In this example there are better ways to do it, or more compact ones like `Array.from()` or `destructuring`or some other hidden jutsu that SO boys know

The latter is very relevant in the context of functional programming, where the data is immutable. And many libraries and frameworks adopt it and recommend it

I have presented an example other than yours because I believe it is more easily demonstrates the usefulness of map

I hope this explanation is useful to you

Answer (score 1):

It is just what other projection/`map`/`select` functions do. It's in the JS spec. In your 2nd example, if `ids` is an array of objects, then it won't work.